# Как прочитать и вывести картинку используя Indy?

Tags: c++, сокет, c++builder, tcp, indy

Как получить картинку с помощью сокетов (Indy tcp client) ?

Есть сервер, который отправляет картинку (любым методом), как ее прочитать и вывести используя компонент от indy? (желательно c++).

Интересует любая информация, примеров крайне мало нашел нормальных.